# how to export and import from blender to c++(.caf, .xrf , .cmf/xmf ....)?

Tags: c++

i like game so much 
at this time i realy try to built simple game , i start wiht build the object and the character (with animation ). but i have big problem to complete this project because i do not know how ti export and imprt this object to c++ , could anyone help me PLEASE??

Answer (score 4):

You say you have a animated character in Blender format and wish to import it into your application written in C++, right?

To export data from Blender and use it in your application, consider using [Open Asset Import Library](http://assimp.sf.net). It reads a huge bunch of file formats. It even supports the native Blender file format, but currently with no animations. *Note - I am biased here, since I'm one of the project's founders*.

Unless it's for learning purposes, I'd strongly discourage you to write your own importers. It's painful and most likely to distract you from your original aim (write a game).

Finding proper exporters for Blender can be tricky, but I'd try Collada, X, MD5, 3DS, Obj, DXF .. usually, one of these formats works (keep in mind, however, that some support animations and more sophisticated materials while others don't).

Answer (score 0):

C++ doesn't support natively 3D graphic rendering nor importing 3D models. My advice would be to first learn how to use Glut or SDL and OpenGL and try to import static models saved in a [obj file format](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/obj/obj.html), which will be way simpler to load and display.